# onclick not working in custom AlertDialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hi in the below code onclick for save if it is empty should show some error or else should move to the next step.but it is not working .Inside frgament I am calling openDiag() method.

can any one help me

```
public class HomeNurseFragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_coordinatorhome, container, false);

        openDialog(rootView);

    public void openDialog(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
           // alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select Hospital and Proceed");
            final View customLayout
                    = getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(
                            R.layout.popup_hospitallist,
                            null);
    
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(customLayout);
            Button save = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.proceed);
            TextView cancel = customLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(hospital.getItemAtPosition(0).equals("Preferred hospital")){
                        hospital.setError("Please select Preferred hospital ");
                    }else {
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    }
                }
            });
     cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    alertDialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
          //  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    
            alertDialogBuilder.show();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you first assign the click listeners and then call `alertDialogBuilder.setView(customLayout)`?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann No it is not working

Comment: Can you add code from where you are calling? I tried calling from activity class & it's working. Getting click listener for save button as well.

Comment: @KishanMaurya inside the fragement

Comment: @KishanMaurya pls check my code  updated

Comment: Tried fragment code as well. its working.
Not sure what logic is for?

if(hospital.getItemAtPosition(0).equals("Preferred hospital")){
                        hospital.setError("Please select Preferred hospital ");
                    }else {
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display an error message instead of dismissing the AlertDialog, you have to disable the clickListener and set your custom one instead.

```
public void openDialog(View view) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    // alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select Hospital and Proceed");
    final View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_hospitallist, null);

     alertDialogBuilder.setView(customLayout);
     alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", null); // set listener to null as you will override it later
     alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
    });

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    // Overriding the Positive button here
    alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {            
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          if(hospital.getItemAtPosition(0).equals("Preferred hospital")){
              hospital.setError("Please select Preferred hospital ");
          } else {
              alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Actually this condition is not excuting if(hospital.getItemAtPosition(0).equals("Preferred hospital")){
              hospital.setError("Please select Preferred hospital ");
          } else {
              alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
          }

Comment: I've edited my answer because a '{' was missing and if I replace the condition by a Toast, the Toast is showing. Try by yourself and if the Toast appears, you may have an error in your condition